# Get Image from Video using Open CV and SimpleUploadedFile

Tags: python, opencv, firebase

I have the following code to create an InMemoryUploadedFile. The reason I'm doing this is because I use firebase and save the images and videos there. It could be considered similar to S3 storage... In my test I have the following:

```
file = BASE_DIR + '/static/samy-assets/img/landing/small.mp4'
video = SimpleUploadedFile(file, open(file, 'rb').read(), content_type="video/mp4")
response = self.client.post('/media/upload/', {'file': video}, follow=True)
```

This works to upload the video to firebase, however now I need to get a frame from the video to show as the "preview". I have this code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(media)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 1000)  # Go to the 1 sec. position
success, frame = cap.read()  # Retrieves the frame at the specified second
print(success)
cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", frame)  # Saves the frame as an image
cv2.waitKey()
```

However the error I receive is:

```
an integer is required (got type InMemoryUploadedFile)
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: what is the `media` variable? `media` should be either an integer (to tell the device number to use, e.g. 0) or a string (like a filename, url), to pass it to the constructor of `VideoCapture`, [look at the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture). Most probably your media is the bytes received, i.e. video in the previous part of code, and it is not recognized. Not sure if it is possible as you are doing it to parse it... Maybe if it is a video format like mjpeg, or maybe saving a local copy or directly the url

Comment: media is a string file name. In this case it is small.mp4

Comment: That is weird, do you know where it gives this error? can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @DenisAngell having the same error, did you find a solution?